# Perform Different Calculations Based on Count Outcome

Tags: postgresql

Today I am attempting to use the COUNT(*) function to return rows that match my criteria as seen below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "mv_fundraiser_report"
WHERE thank_you_delivered = true
```

What I am attempting to do is to perform a different calculation based on the number that is returned. For instance:

```
If COUNT > 2000
RETURN COUNT * 2

If COUNT < 2000
RETURN COUNT * 3
```

I'm looking for guidance as to how I could execute this task within PostgreSQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using condition expression [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-conditional.html)

```
select case 
        when cnt > 2000
            then cnt * 2
        else cnt * 3
        end new_cnt
from (
    select COUNT(*) as cnt
    from "mv_fundraiser_report"
    where thank_you_delivered = true
    ) t
```